# Wildcards in machine specific builds

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Assumed I have those machines:

- machine1a
- machine1b
- machine2

Is there a way to respond all machine1s at once?

For example in a *.bbappend file:

```
SRC_URI_machine1* += "file://file/for/machines/of/type/1"
```

instead of:

```
SRC_URI_machine1a += "file://file/for/machines/of/type/1"
SRC_URI_machine1b += "file://file/for/machines/of/type/1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,wildcards can't be used in such a way.

You could handle it in a number of different way. One way is to add a common machine-override for your family of devices.

One simple way to do this, is to add the following to the machine configurations of machine1a and machine1b (or a common include file).

```
SOC_FAMILY = "machine1-common"
include conf/machine/include/soc-family.inc
```

By doing that, you could write

```
SRC_URI_machine1-common += "file://file/for/machines/of/type/1"
```

and that would apply to both machine1a and machine1b.

What `soc-family.inc` does is

```
# Add SOC_FAMILY to machine overrides so we get access to e.g. 'omap3' and 'ti335x'
SOC_FAMILY ??= ""
MACHINEOVERRIDES =. "${@['', '${SOC_FAMILY}:']['${SOC_FAMILY}' != '']}"
```

If you're already using an SoC, whose BSP already uses `SOC_FAMILY`, you could instead add the following line to `machine1a.conf` and `machine1b.conf`

```
MACHINEOVERRIDES =. "machine1-common:"
```

Comment: Ok thanks for you answer. So as example `SRC_URI_machine1-common` would be for both of the machines?

Comment: Yes,  `SRC_URI_machine1-common` will apply to all machines, which has `machine1-common` in its `MACHINEOVERRIDES`.

Comment: Ok, so thats exactly what I searched. thank you very much.